# log all requests done with gulp-connect

Tags: node.js, gulp

I use gulp-connect with proxy-middleware.

```
var proxy_function = function(connect, o) {
    return [

        ,(function() {
        var url = require('url');
        var proxy = require('proxy-middleware');
        var options = url.parse(a);
        options.route = b;
        return proxy(options);
    })() ];
};

gulp.task('connect', function() {
    connect.server({
        port: '8002',
        root: build_dest,
        middleware: proxy_function
    });
});
```

There is something with the proxy function which does not work out so i want o log the actual request done by the proxy.

How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var connect = require('gulp-connect');

function accessLog(req, res, next) {
  gutil.log(req.method, req.url, 'HTTP/' + req.httpVersion, res.statusCode);
  next();
}

gulp.task('connect', function() {
  connect.server({
    port: 8002,
    root: build_dest,
    middleware: function(connect, opt) {
      return [accessLog];
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I have tried this code, but `res.statusCode` always return `200` even if the resource requested is not exist. Anything wrong I had done?